# Show that the system of linear equations has a non-trivial solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Show that the system of linear equations has a non-trivial solution 
   $\leftrightarrow$ $\alpha = \beta$

$$x+y+\alpha.z=0$$ 
$$x+y+\beta.z=0$$
$$\alpha.x+\beta.y+z=0$$

How could it be demonstrated?

Answer (score 2):

The determinant of the coefficient matrix  is $-(\alpha -\beta)^{2}$ which is $0$ iff $\alpha =\beta$.

Comment: @Mason Of course! Thank you.